# Force an app to restart rather than resume after deactivation

Tags: windows-phone-8, restart

Is there a way to indicate to the os that my app be fresh restarted rather than activated and resumed when it becomes deactivated?

Answer (score 1):

The [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.activated%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Event is published whenever a user returns and the app gets resumed.

> Activated - Occurs when the application is being made active after previously being put into a dormant state or tombstoned.

See about all the events and interception possibilities here on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

If you wan't to change the start- and restart behavior, have a look at the [fast app resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) option.